# Use boot2docker or native docker install?

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I would like to use docker on a Linux environnent so I have 2 options :

- [Native install of docker on my linux mint](https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/)
- [Use docker via a VM with boot2docker (or Vagrant/puppet)](http://boot2docker.io/)

I think that the VM way is more easy to install but you may have some difficulties to share data between your laptop and docker container (you have to install guest addition in virualbox for example ...)

On the other hand, the native install seems less easy but I think you gain some performance and sharing data more easily  ...

So I would like to know, for you what are the advantages/inconvenients of the 2 methods ?

What was your choice and why ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 9):

## Native installation of Docker

- If you are already on Linux, there is simply no need for another tool and layer like a VM
- Better performance (since you are not in a VM, but on your machine directly)
- It is pretty easy, e.g. to install Docker on Ubuntu 14 just run `curl -sSL https://get.docker.io/ubuntu/ | sudo sh`

## VM/Boot2Docker

- Docker will not "pollute" your system - if you don't want to use Docker anymore, just throw away your VM, nothing will be left on your system

If you are on Linux already, I would just install Docker and you are done.

Comment: Your right. to begin, I will use boot2docker in conjunction with vagrant  (https://vagrantcloud.com/yungsang/boot2docker) to easily sync folder, etc ...  And if it's usefull for me I will install it in native mode :)

Comment: @user3083061 I do not see the point of not installing docker directly on your gnu/linux ... boot2docker is really helpfull for the dev on mac or windows but on gnu/linux come on !

Comment: boot2docker may make sense on Linux if you have an old (pre 3.8?) kernel that you can't upgrade

Comment: Another advantage to using boot2docker on Linux is the case that you have developers on multiple platforms.  See https://blog.codeship.com/cross-platform-docker-development-environment/